How to remove these unknown spots from window glass? Maybe insect or angle grinder damage?
I recently moved into a new flat and noticed that one of the windows to the balcony has these brown spots on the glass. They are very hard to remove, and when I tried to scrape one of the spots off, it still left some white residue that I cannot get rid of. On close inspection, it looks a bit like rust. After some Googling, I'm wondering if it could be damage from an angle grinder, or maybe I'm just not using the right cleaner?


I believe you are correct with the angle grinder damage, or hot metal impaction.

Did you use a razor blade paint scraper made for windows/glass?  That should remove it unless the glass surface is damaged/pitted.
